# Linux bash scripting [ CLEAR command and SSH with watch problem ]

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scripting, monitor

So i got 2 questions regarding linux bash scripting and can't figure out any solution posted in the forum (just started BASH scripting).

I  got a script that monitors a specific server , giving me the disk usage , cpu usage...etc  (i am using 2 ubuntu VMs : i run the script in the server using SSH [ssh user@ip < script.sh] from the first VM ), and i wanted to make it show real time values so i tried 2 solutions i found in here first one is using a while loop with "clear;" command to make the script run multiple times giving new values every time and deleting the previous printed results like so

```
while true
do
      clear; 
      //bunch of code
done
```

The first problem is that it doesnt clear the terminal it just keeps printing the new result one after another.

The second problem came when i wanted to change the approach and tried to use the " watch -n 1 Script.h" command , which works fine on the local machine (to monitor the current machine where the script is)  but i can't find a way to make it run along side  SSH something like : ssh user@ip < 'watch -n 1 script.sh' which in this case the script must be in the server itself  to work , and i don't want it that way , so is there any way to run "watch" on the script  from the local machine into the server?

thanks in advance !

Comment: Perhaps also ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should achieve what you wanted :

```
watch -n 1 bash -c "'ssh -tt user@ip < script.sh'"
```

`-tt` forces tty creation.

Comment: doesn't seem to work it's giving weird characters to the output  can't even read it anymore

Comment: For debugging purposes, put a single string `date` in script.sh, and give it a test.
Also I updated `ssh` in my answer